# Jquery Image Slide Up After Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pls I am working on a website. I want a situation on the home page where an image of a man standing will slide up 1 or 2 seconds after the whole page has loaded. I need someone to help me with a codepen example.

Below is the code I inserted in the head section. I set the image to display:none in css, but when I refresh, I found out it's not working. #man is the id of the image.

Thank u.

```
$(function() {
    $("#man").one('load', function () {
        $(this).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 2000);
    }).each(function() { 
        if(this.complete)
            $(this).load();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#man").show("slide", {
      direction: "up"
   }, 2000);
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/CqR9E/2/

Comment: Pls will i need to hide the image with css? will i need to download any jquery file from jquery.com?

Comment: @AlexUzor yes for a "show" animation, the starting state of the element must be "invisible" (display: none), so you have to hide it with css
to include jquery and other libraries, you can use the free cdn-driven hosting of google: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Yes, you need to hide the image first.You also need to include jquery. for more info. see the posted demo in my answer

Comment: @AlexUzor : see this to know how to include jquery 'view-source:http://jsfiddle.net/CqR9E/2/show/'

Comment: <head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#man").show("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
</head> Am sorry but this is not working here. The image i want to slide in is inside a fixed div. So when the image slides in, it will be fixed and not scroll as its parent is fixed. ur jsfiddle is working fine. but when i copied ur exact codes and tried it, it was not working. am using a localhost.

Comment: @AlexUzor You need to include jqueryui.js also `-->` `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: It's still not working. what might be the problem? I add these: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script> I also added this:  $(window).load(function () {
        $("#man").show("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 1000);
    }); Here is my css: <style>#man{width:400px;height:600px;display:none;background:red;}</style>

Comment: Ok, look if their is any error on your browser console  `-->` press `F12` to open it

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(anonymous function)
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
(anonymous function)

Comment: That is because jquery is not loaded properly :  use this instead :  `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank u. It's working now. But i want a situation where the image will delay for 5 seconds and then fires in with speed. And i want if the user refreshes the page, it will not repeat again.

Comment: Can i stop it from replaying even if the user reloads the page?

Comment: Yes, but that is a totally different thing , i suggest you to post a new question with that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need all that...the below code will slide up after a 2000 ms delay:

```
slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#man').slideUp();
}, 2000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/VBtUU/

Comment: Pls will i need to hide the image with css? will i need to download any jquery file from jquery.com?

Comment: This will hide it for you.

Comment: but that is a diffrent logic - the first posted code-snippet will show the image over an animation-duration of 2 seconds - this one will hide the first visible image after two seconds.. and its dangerous using a setInterval for a one-time-job.. it will execute every two seconds.. better using setTimeout